# How to 'git remote add' and track a branch in the same filesystem

Tags: git

I have 2 local git archives in /a and in /b which were cloned from remotes/origin.

There is a new branch z on /b

How can I track and fetch branch z from archive /a ?

I tried this:

```
cd /a
git remote add b /b
```

This creates 2 config entries, but I did not manage to fetch something or to list remote branches on /a that would show the branches on /b

---

After trying different things I found the following that works:

1) `git remote show b` lists all the remote branches in b

2) I can fetch using this syntax:

`git fetch file:///a/ z`

---

Other things that also work:

```
$ cd /b
$ git checkout -b z
Switched to a new branch 'z'
$ git pull b z
```

---

But those commands still dont work and I cannot understand why:

```
git branch -a
```

does not list the remote branches in b (onlz the ones in origin are shown)

```
git checkout -t b/z
```

Does not checkout anything but returns an error message

Comment: I might just be confused, but it looks like you're under the impression git branches are directories like subversion branches (they aren't).

Comment: @coreyward: no, I think mit has two separate local clones

Comment: "`git pull b z`" what does that do? Doesn't branch z only exist in repo b? Or is it actually pulling from repo a? (I wouldn't expect it to since you didn't add repo a as a remote to repo b.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So far you've only added b as a remote. You can try `git branch -a` to list your remote branches after you've fetched them.

Here's the commands to checkout the z branch from b:

```
git remote add b /b              # you've already done
git fetch b                      # get it so we can see it
git checkout -t b/z              # check out a local tracking branch
```

The `-t` (or `--track`) creates a tracking branch, otherwise you'll be in detached head state.

Then you should see:

```
/a$ git branch
  master
* z
```

---

For anyone unclear on the steps involved, here's what I did:

create origin

```
$ mkdir origin
$ cd origin/
/origin$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /origin/
/origin$ cd ..
```

clone 'a' and add some content

```
$ git clone origin/ a
Initialized empty Git repository in /a/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
$ cd a
/a$ echo hi there > hello
/a$ git add hello
/a$ git ci -m'first commit'
[master (root-commit) 0867b93] first commit
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 hello
/a$ git push origin master 
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 210 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To /origin/
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

clone 'b' and add more content on new branch

```
/a$ cd ..
$ git clone origin/ b
Initialized empty Git repository in /b/.git/
$ cd b
/b$ git checkout -b z
Switched to a new branch 'z'
/b$ echo new guy reporting in >> hello 
/b$ git ci -am "new recruits"
[z 81044ee] new recruits
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Add 'b' as a remote to 'a'

```
/b$ cd ../a
/a$ git remote add b ../b
/a$ git fetch b
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From ../b
 * [new branch]      master     -> b/master
 * [new branch]      z          -> b/z
/a$ git br
* master
/a$ git checkout -t b/z
Branch z set up to track remote branch z from b.
Switched to a new branch 'z'
/a$ git br
  master
* z
```

I've put the above [commands into a script](https://gist.github.com/849624) so you can test it out yourself.

Comment: if you still have the archives from your example, could you post the output of `git config -l` (when in /a) ?

Comment: I believe I followed your instructions, but there are 2 things that do not work here. 1) git branch -a lists only the remote branches in origin, but not in the other archive that I just `remote added`. 2)  git checkout -t b/z results in an error message: `fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches. Did you intend to checkout 'b/z' which can not be resolved as commit?`

Comment: @mit: Sorry, I missed a step in my summary. I think that error is because you haven't done `git fetch b` from repo a.

Comment: thank you, I tried the script and it works. This really helps a lot, I can build an extended workflow now :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.

I think you'll need to push branch z to origin in b and fetch it from a.

```
cd /b
git push origin z
```

That last command pushes local branch z to remote (so pushing z -> origin/z)

then you can track it locally in repo a:

```
cd /a
git checkout -b z origin/z
```

That last command creates (and checks out) a *local* branch z that tracks origin/z

Comment: Git _never_ forces you to use a centralized repository (of course permissions and guidelines may restrict your options). Each repo is just as important as all the other ones. So adding `b` as a remote to `a` is definitely possible and mit even accomplished it above. The only thing missing is the correct checkout command -- see my answer.